# How to idiomatically support closing values with pairs()?

Tags: loops, lua

I'm new to Lua (language version 5.4 if it matters, there doesn't seem to be a tag for that version on SO yet) and I'm trying to find the most idiomatic way to implement iteration (`for` loop) over a userdata object.

The [Lua 5.4 Reference Manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html) says regarding a loop statement `for var_1, ···, var_n in explist do body end`:

> The loop starts by evaluating explist to produce four values: an iterator function, a state, an initial value for the control variable, and a closing value.

The idiomatic way to loop seems to be using the `pairs(t)` function. This also works for userdata via the `__pairs` metamethod. However:

> If t has a metamethod __pairs, calls it with t as argument and returns the first three results from the call.

Why only three instead of four? If I have a complex userdata object that needs to allocate some resource for a loop, I'll need that closing value so I know when to deallocate that resource in case the loop ends early, right? Does that mean I cannot use `pairs` in such a case or am I missing something?

I could of course provide a new function, say `pairs4`, but that doesn't seem to be very idiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because that's how it has always worked since at least Lua 5.0. `pairs` always returned 3 values because `for` previously only took 3 values.

["to-be-closed variables" are a new feature of Lua 5.4](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#3.3.8), as is the fourth value for generic `for`. Why `pairs` wasn't updated to match is unknown. It is possible that `pairs` returns all of the values from the `__pairs` metamethod, but I haven't looked at the implementation to verify this.

In this case, I would suggest writing a `pairs_close` that returns 4 arguments from the `__pairs` metamethod.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know this was a "brand new" feature. FWIW, I checked: the C implementation does indeed return only three values (https://github.com/lua/lua/blob/v5.4.0/lbaselib.c#L272), while the Go implementation simply returns however many return values there are (https://github.com/arnodel/golua/blob/lua5.4/lib/base/pairs.go#L17). Code meant to be portable should therefore, as you suggest, provide its own implementation.